# What happens if two people at the same host claim ownership of a domain?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, nameserver

I have all my domains registered through company A and they are hosted through company B. I set my nameservers at company A to point to dns.companyB.com and everything works great.

But couldn't somebody else with an account through company B also try to claim ownership in their control panel? Is it first-come first-served?

Comment: Only one person can own a domain and the owner can control and configure its DNS.

Comment: this happened to us. our registrar stated there were two account (ours and another account) that both owned our domain???! They had to synchronize the DNZ zone to fix it, as indeed we owned the domain, not them.

Answer (score 1):

The uniqueness of a domain zone is an important (if not fundamental) requirement of every DNS provider. Generally speaking, the DNS infrastructure of a DNS provider should be designed to allow only one specific instance of the same domain zone.

It means that if you registered the domain `example.com` with foocompany and you are hosting the DNS with barcompany, if I create an account in barcompany I should not be able to create a domain in my account called `example.com`.

If I could, then it means than the company MUST have a way to determine who is the authoritative ownwer. But this makes things more complicated, and there is no reason to follow this way.

However, I may be able to create an account with bazcompany and publish there a zone for `example.com` regardless I'm the registrant or not. But this has no real effect.

Because you are managing the domain, as long as the name server for the domain are pointing to barcompany, the domain will resolve with the configuration you created in your barcompany account.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  What if some other customer of the same hosting company had created configuration for the domain?  Then you point your domain at the server and it shows somebody else's content!